# Create tuples of (lemma, NER type) in python , Nlp problem

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I wrote the code below, and I made a dictionary for it, but I want Create tuples of (lemma, NER type) and Collect counts over the tuples I dont know how to do it? can you pls help me? NER type means name entity recognition

```
text = """
Seville.
Summers in the flamboyant Andalucían capital often nudge 40C, but spring is a delight, with the parks in bloom and the scent of orange blossom and jasmine in the air. And in Semana Santa (Holy Week, 14-20 April) the streets come alive with floats and processions. There is also the raucous annual Feria de Abril – a week-long fiesta of parades, flamenco and partying long into the night (4-11 May; expect higher hotel prices if you visit then).
Seville is a romantic and energetic place, with sights aplenty, from the Unesco-listed cathedral – the largest Gothic cathedral in the world – to the beautiful Alcázar royal palace. But days here are best spent simply wandering the medieval streets of Santa Cruz and along the river to La Real Maestranza, Spain’s most spectacular bullring.
Seville is the birthplace of tapas and perfect for a foodie break – join a tapas tour (try devoursevillefoodtours.com), or stop at the countless bars for a glass of sherry with local jamón ibérico (check out Bar Las Teresas in Santa Cruz or historic Casa Morales in Constitución). Great food markets include the Feria, the oldest, and the wooden, futuristic-looking Metropol Parasol.
Nightlife is, unsurprisingly, late and lively. For flamenco, try one of the peñas, or flamenco social clubs – Torres Macarena on C/Torrijano, perhaps – with bars open across town until the early hours.
Book it: In an atmospheric 18th-century house, the Hospes Casa del Rey de Baeza is a lovely place to stay in lively Santa Cruz. Doubles from £133 room only, hospes.com
Trieste.
"""

doc = nlp(text).ents
en = [(entity.text, entity.label_) for entity in doc]
en
#entities
#The list stored in variable entities is has type list[list[tuple[str, str]]],
#from pprint import pprint
pprint(en)

sum(filter(None, entities), [])

from collections import defaultdict
type2entities = defaultdict(list)
for entity, entity_type in sum(filter(None, entities), []):
  type2entities[entity_type].append(entity)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(type2entities)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following code snippets solve your problem.

```
import spacy

# Load English tokenizer, tagger, parser, NER and word vectors
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

text = ("Seville.
Summers in the flamboyant Andalucían capital often nudge 40C, but spring is a delight, with the parks in bloom and the scent of orange blossom and jasmine in the air. And in Semana Santa (Holy Week, 14-20 April) the streets come alive with floats and processions. There is also the raucous annual Feria de Abril – a week-long fiesta of parades, flamenco and partying long into the night (4-11 May; expect higher hotel prices if you visit then).
Seville is a romantic and energetic place, with sights aplenty, from the Unesco-listed cathedral – the largest Gothic cathedral in the world – to the beautiful Alcázar royal palace. But days here are best spent simply wandering the medieval streets of Santa Cruz and along the river to La Real Maestranza, Spain’s most spectacular bullring.
Seville is the birthplace of tapas and perfect for a foodie break – join a tapas tour (try devoursevillefoodtours.com), or stop at the countless bars for a glass of sherry with local jamón ibérico (check out Bar Las Teresas in Santa Cruz or historic Casa Morales in Constitución). Great food markets include the Feria, the oldest, and the wooden, futuristic-looking Metropol Parasol.
Nightlife is, unsurprisingly, late and lively. For flamenco, try one of the peñas, or flamenco social clubs – Torres Macarena on C/Torrijano, perhaps – with bars open across town until the early hours.
Book it: In an atmospheric 18th-century house, the Hospes Casa del Rey de Baeza is a lovely place to stay in lively Santa Cruz. Doubles from £133 room only, hospes.com
Trieste.")

doc = nlp(text)

lemma_ner_list = [] 

for entity in doc.ents: 
   lemma_ner_list.append((entity.lemma_, entity.label_)) 

# print list of lemma ner tuples

print(lemma_ner_list)

# print count of tuples

print(len(lemma_ner_list))
```

Comment: but when I run it tells :TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given) do you know how to solve this?

Comment: my mistake, I have edited the answer, you can try to add parenthesis around lemma entity pair. Parenthesis makes this pair a tuple.

Comment: sorry this is extra question, do you know how can I find out the 10 most frequent tuples? thank you in advance

Comment: You can use python ```collection``` package.  You following code snippet: ```from collections import Counter  \n Counter(lemma_ner_list).most_common(10)```